# Two floated columns - one fixed, one loose width

Tags: html, css, css-float

I've looked around `SO`, but I cannot find one that matches my occurrence, I basically have two columns one fixed width (185px) and the other column has no fixed width, however I need the last column to fill the last space, e.g.

```
...........................................
.---------  ------------------------------.
.+       +  +                            +.
.+       +  +                            +.
.+       +  +                            +.
.+       +  +                            +.
.+       +  ------------------------------.
.+       +                                .
.+       +                                .
.+       +                                .
.---------                                .
...........................................
```

The first column should always be 100% to the bottom when the second column fills the remaining width, they both are floated `left`, if I resize the browser window, the second column shows under the first column. I need the second column to fill the remaining width and be flexible when resizing the browser window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-2-column-left-menu-pixels.htm).
There aren't any demos, but I've used tutorials from this guy before so I assume it works fine. I gather from the article that the main content is liquid. The side content may also be liquid, but I think you can just give it a fixed width and leave it at that. The trick here is to place the main content  first.

Answer (score 66):

There's actually an easier way to do it than using floats:

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.left {
    width: 185px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.right {
    margin-left: 185px;
}
```

Comment: This works great... but after the container i have footer... what happening is... the footer is not goes after the container... instead its became middle of the container.

Comment: @Jacob is that possible to use % instead of specific pixel?

Comment: The right width isn't going to stretch 100% if the content isn't big enough though?

Answer (score 9):

By using negative margins [from this tutorial](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/) the CSS can look as follows

```css
html, body, .container {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.container {
    min-width: 300px;
}
.left {
    float:left;
    width: 185px;
    margin-right: -185px;
    height:100%;
}
.right {
    margin-left:185px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y5FAT/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/Y5FAT/

Answer (score 8):

Edited the solution, this time using flexbox, made the left column fixed using `flex: 185px 0 0;` then made the right column auto grow using `flex-grow:1`

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

#container{
  display:flex;
}

#left{
  height: 100vh;
  flex: 185px 0 0;
  background-color:tomato;
}

#right{
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#right > div{
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="left"> Left </div>
      <div id="right">
        <div>
        Right <br/>
        dsafasfadf dsafdsfasdf asfasdf adfasdf dsafasfadf dsafasfadf dsafdsfasdf asfasdf adfasdf dsafasfadf  dsafasfadf dsafdsfasdf asfasdf adfasdf dsafasfadf dsafdsfasdf asfasdf adfasdf   dsafasfadf dsafdsfasdf asfasdf adfasdf dsafasfadf dsafdsfasdf asfasdf adfasdf   dsafasfadf dsafdsfasdf asfasdf adfasdf dsafasfadf dsafdsfasdf asfasdf adfasdf   dsafasfadf dsafdsfasdf asfasdf adfasdf dsafasfadf dsafdsfasdf asfasdf adfasdf   dsafasfadf dsafdsfasdf asfasdf adfasdf dsafasfadf dsafdsfasdf asfasdf adfasdf 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: The right column will not automatically fill the available space like this, but instead use the minimal required room to display its contents.

Comment: @TimothyGroote here is my updated solution using ```flexbox```,the right column should now fill/grow to the available space  https://jsfiddle.net/ouymLfoz/ thanks.

Comment: Ok, that seems to work. but why didn't you just update the answer?

Answer (score 2):

The "position: absolute;" answer is pretty good, but it has cross-browser implications, especially if you're developing for IE. The best way to accomplish this is the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    div.right {
        float: right;
        width: 200px;
    }
    div.left {
        margin-right: 200px;
    }
    div.clear {
        clear: both;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="right"><!--your code here--></div>
    <div class="left"><!--your code here--></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note that the div you require on the right side is called first in the HTML. Also, note the clearing of the float after the columns, which will come in handy if you have content below, or if there is a parent container.

Comment: Note; it's bad practice having styles in the head section, regardless of it being a demo. It's also bad practice selecting elements in CSS by element name and class name (e.g. div.right) - just class name will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use neither floats nor absolute positioning, the easiest I could come up with was

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
      div.left {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 200px;
        white-space: normal;
        background-color: red;
        vertical-align: top;
      }
      div.right {
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: normal;
        background-color: green;
      }
    </style>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="left">
      left
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      right
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, approved answer ia a good one, but for those that are searching for more here is a link.
Hope you find this useful. ;)

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/category/C13/

Answer (score 1):

I had tried almost all of the above solution until i stumbled upon this, and it works wonderfully for me. [How to make a div to fill a remaining horizontal space (a very simple but annoying problem for CSS experts)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5955286/1557270)

Not sure why, it seems you only need to float the column that has fixed width. The rest just fall in to place.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem using [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.left {
    width: 185px;
    /* height: 200px; */
    flex: none;
}

.right {
    flex: auto;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).