# Is there a way for a <div> to take up full height and all available horizontal space without absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a page with three basic elements: a header, a sidebar, and a `<div>` that will contain a Google map. The header has a fixed size and full width; below that, the sidebar is on the left and has a fixed width, while the map is on the right and should expand to fill all available width. It looks something like this:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|                  header                      |
+-------------+--------------------------------+
|             |                                |
|             |                                |
|             |                                |
|   sidebar   |              map               |
|             |                                |
|             |                                |
|             |                                |
+-------------+--------------------------------+
```

So far, my layout could be accomplished using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032914/how-to-make-a-div-to-fill-a-remaining-horizontal-space-a-very-simple-but-annoyi). The problem is that I want both the map and the sidebar to take up all available *vertical* space too. I managed to get this working by absolutely positioning the map and the sidebar, but then I couldn't set a background-gradient on the page because the `<body>` was only as tall as the header--the sidebar and map were not part of the document flow.

Is it possible to achieve this combination of fixed-size and flexible objects while leaving the `<body>` with a reasonable height?

Comment: set html and body height to 100%

Comment: @SvenBieder With what combination of floating/positioning on the elements?

Comment: Setting 100% height for `<html>` and `<body>` should be sufficient to fix the problem you had with your absolute positioning solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to use:

```
body, html {height:100%}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure!

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FTD86/

This approach uses a combination of absolutely positioned items for the fixed size header and sidebar and padding in the containers to account for these fixed sized items. Notice the borders, which let you know these are properly sized :)

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <header></header>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="sidebar">

        </div>
        <div class="map">     
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

​
CSS:

```
body, html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;    
}

.main{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding-top:100px;
}

.main header{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:5px solid #ffff00;
    background:#333333;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.main .content{
    position:relative;
    background:#eeeeee;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding-left:150px;
}

.main .content .sidebar{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:5px solid #ff00ff;
    background:#336699;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:150px;
    height:100%;
}

.main .content .map{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:5px solid #ffffff;
    background:#ff0000;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;    
}
​
```

​