# Why DIVS are collapsing with windows size reduction?

Tags: html, css, text

I don't know why the text in my HTML page is collapsing inside the menu, here you can find my page in [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/KXDZb/).

Some of my HTML file:

```
<div class="menu">
    item 1
    item 2
    ...
</div>
<div class="content">
    text text text
</div>
```

Some of my CSS file:

```
.menu{
float: left;
padding-top: 100px;
width: 20%;
position: relative;
}
.content{
float: right;
padding-top: 100px;
width: 80%;
color: #dddddd;
position: relative;
}
```

Is it a css problem with the width %? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining `.menu` and `.content` as being `20%` and `80%` the width of the *window* - your containers are being sized properly.

However, you've set a width of `150px` and padding of `30px` on your `.grezzo` nodes, which causes them to expand outside of the `.menu` div (if the window is too small)

Try removing the width on `.grezzo`

Comment: so my "buttons" will use the `.menu` width instead?

Comment: If you want that, yeah.  If you want a fixed width `.menu` and flexible `.content`, then you don't want to use `%` based widths at all

Answer (score 0):

It is because your left div has content that sticks out further than the container. Therefore, your text(right) div is actually right up against the left div like it is supposed to be, but the buttons are extending out of the left div.

To solve this, you either need to resize your button images, or let the left div automatically resize to hold them and the right div just takes all remaining space as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032914/how-to-make-a-div-to-fill-a-remaining-horizontal-space-a-very-simple-but-annoyi).

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `float: left;` on your menu element.  Also, if you remove your `width` on your `.content` and `.menu`, they text will not overlay the menu.