# CSS: Make a div fill remaining space on right-hand side, without inner content overflowing

Tags: css, html

I have a fixed-width left div, and I want to make the right div fill the remaining space.

So far I've been [taking this approach recommended by another SO poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032914/how-to-make-a-div-to-fill-a-remaining-horizontal-space-a-very-simple-but-annoyi), but it doesn't work if I have content inside the right div.

The content in the right div is set to `width: 100%`, so I would expect it to be no wider than the right-hand div, but it overflows the right div.

```
<div>
  <div id="left">left</div>
  <div id="right">right<div id="insideright">overflows</div</div>
</div>

<style>
#left {
    float:left;
    width:180px;
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
#right {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#00FF00;
}
#insideright { 
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: blue; 
    height: 5px;
}
</style>
```

JSFiddle here, demoing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/MHeqG/155/

What can I do?

I want to support older IE browsers, so I'd rather not use `display: table-cell` etc if I can avoid it, or at least not without a reasonable fallback.

Comment: Can you clarify your question by referencing the actual id of the div(s) you're talking about? "The content in the right div..." which right div?

Comment: please define "older browsers"

Comment: its  overflowing because you set its width property to 100% of the screen right next to a floated element. It continues all the way because the there is no element to stop it. you should use a clear fix after floats

Comment: do you want to avoid the overflow all together OR just overflow to the far left?

Answer (score 7):

Actually it's pretty simple... don't add `100%` to the right div :)
just add the `overflow` property

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iHaFODO/2/edit)***

```
#left {
  float:left;
  width:180px;
  background-color:#ff0000;
}
#right {
  overflow:auto;
  background-color:#00FF00;
}
#insideright { 
  background-color: blue; 
}
```

...and if you even wondered how to make the red (left) div fill the remaining height...
[***DEMO***](http://jsbin.com/iHaFODO/3/edit)

Comment: I was about to post exactly what you had for your second demo...nice

Comment: @JonP thanks!, yeah, I made it immediately so I don't need to do it later. If not by the OP might have been asked by others.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do (your references to `right` are ambiguous). But if I'm understanding, you want the `insideright` to be nested within the `right` without overflowing?

Why not use a `<span>` instead? `<div>` out of the box is `display: block;` which will force a wrap like that. Alternatively, override this behavior by using `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`.

```
<div>
    <div id="left">
        left
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        right
        <span id="insideright">this should not overflow right</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/brandonscript/MHeqG/157/

Comment: I agree, if you can use a `<span>` do that.

Comment: this is not true, just add a `<br>` and you're at the beginning of the question.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan that will overflow `right` not `insideright` though? Really, it's tough to fix this in this context - I'd need to see a real-world example to improve the answer. Unless of course we're talking `overflow: hidden;` or `white-space: no-wrap;` but that's an entirely different question/answer.