# Make an input take up all the remaining space

Tags: css, fill-parent

My problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1032914/581205), but different.

I have a table cell of an *unknown* width. This cell contains an `input` and a `span`. The `span` should be *as wide as its contents needs* and the `input` should *take all the remaining space*.

I've created a trivial [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/H0KzxVbRKNxuNjFLt0Dr?p=preview) for this seemingly trivial question. The random text should be on the very right and the input should grow or shrink as needed to fill the yellow `td`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try splitting the yellow `<td>` into its own table (or other elements using `display: table-cell`, etc).

Set the width of the cell containing the input to 100%, and set the max-width of the table to 100%.

That will cause the table inside the cell to re-flow when the text changes.

Basic demo: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/ao4at9RHg8VgRrgtmTqu?p=preview

Comment: This works nicely... I see now I forgot that there are whitespaces (and whatever) in the real text, but `white-space: nowrap;` solves this complication.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with Flexbox.

HTML:

```
<td class="foo">
    <input class="foo__input">
    <span>dsflkwej</span>                
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.foo {
    display: flex
}
.foo__input {
    flex-grow: 1
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/MhR77/

(Use Autoprefixer to add vendor prefixes for Flexbox properties.)

Comment: What browser does it work in out of the box? I have Chromium 25 and FF 20 and it doesn't work. I've added `-moz-` and `-webkit-` manually and nothing has changed.

Comment: @maaartinus Firefox is currently at version 30. Are you sure that you have version 20? *** In order to use CSS Flexbox today, you have to provide vendor prefixes. I recommend Autoprefixer. You can either use it as part of your CSS build process (in conjunction to e.g. a minifier, linter, …) or you can copy pasted the full code via this [online tool](http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/udyTs/show/light/).

Comment: Yes, I'm using FF version 20. And that's most probably because of Ubuntu 10.04. And that's because I haven't found any single real improvement in any newer Ubuntu. Anyway, I'll have look at the Autoprefixer.