# Div auto expand width right column

Tags: html

Given the following HTML, I want the second div to appear to the right of the fixed size red box, auto expanding to the full width of the browser.  What am I missing?

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div style="width: 100%;">
   <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid red; float: left; clear: both; background-color: red;">
   </div>
   <div style="border: 1px solid red; float: left; background-color: blue; color: white;">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum  
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a div to fill a remaining horizontal space (a very simple but annoying problem for CSS experts)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032914/how-to-make-a-div-to-fill-a-remaining-horizontal-space-a-very-simple-but-annoyi)

Comment: Most excellent.  Thanks.  I searched all kinds of terms and never found that one.