# Make left div fill the remaining space

Tags: html, css, flexbox, ellipsis

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1032952/288568) I try to make the left div to fill up remaining space, left and right should always be in one line where the right div should be fully visible.

How to accomplish that?

```css
#left {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  float: left;
}
#right {
  float: right;
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div id="left">
      left text should have the remaining width and shortended if it is too long lorem ipsum minion dolor
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      this text is dynamic - should be fully visibile
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Edit**:

Flex-box answer not working. It looks like that if the green text becomes shorter:

[image]

What I want is the green div to become smaller now, when the text is short.

Comment: you want both div in one line? why no float on left div?

Comment: Yes exactly ... added float left, does not help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy if you are opting for a `flexbox` - see demo below:

1. Add `display: flex` to your wrapper and remove the *float*s
2. Add `white-space:nowrap` to `right`

```css
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
}
#left {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  flex:1;
}
#right {
  background-color: #00FF00;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="left">
    left text should have the remaining width and shortended if it is too long lorem ipsum minion dolor
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    this text is dynamic - should be fully visibile
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does not seem to work, see my edit to the question and screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**.

Make the parent `<div>` a flex container using `display: flex;` and give both `#left` & `#right` `flex: 1;`

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.holder {
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#right {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>This is My Page's Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="holder">
    <div id="left">
      left text should have the remaining width and shortended if it is too long lorem ipsum minion dolor
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      this text is dynamic - should be fully visibile
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps!