# How to position two divs side by side where the first fills width 100% if second div not present?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align two div's side by side, but when the second div isn't displayed, I want the first div to have width 100%.

Sorry for not using the correct post format but I hope you can understand my question.
Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Where is your CSS? Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Check out the `flexbox` and `flex-grow` property ;-)

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25117686/8620333