# Stretch inputs to fill div's width?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that looks like this:

[image: picture with un-stretched inputs]

I would like to somehow make the inputs always stretch to the end of the div. The desired result is:

[image: picture with inputs stretched to end of div]

It seems from the research I did that adding `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap` to the div will be necessary, but I couldn't get it to layout as desired. Any help on how to make the inputs always stretch to the end of the div will be appreciated.

If the input breaks to own line that's fine. I just want it to stretch to the end of the div.

Code snippet to follow -

```css
.square:nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgb(220, 217, 217);
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33%);
  column-gap: .5%;
}

.square {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.square input {

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="square one">

      <label for="numSelect">Choose an algorithm:</label>
      <input type="text" id="numSelect">

      <label for="arr">Array:</label>
      <input type="text" id="arr">

    </div>
    <div class="square 2">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square 3">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square 4">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square 5">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square 6">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a div fill a remaining horizontal space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032914/how-to-make-a-div-fill-a-remaining-horizontal-space) (obviously replace `div` with `input` but you will get the idea....)

Comment: [**This answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25117686/3536236) should help you

Comment: You state: "If the input breaks to own line that's fine. I just want it to stretch to the end of the div." so the solution can be : `input[type='text']{ display:inline-block;min-width:100%; }` . Simple.

Comment: Thanks @Martin. That linked answer does work when I add `flex-wrap: wrap;` and setting the text width using percentage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap;` to `.one` like below:

```css
.square:nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgb(220, 217, 217);
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33%);
  column-gap: .5%;
}

.square {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.square input {

}

.one {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="square one">

      <label for="numSelect">Choose an algorithm:</label>
      <input type="text" id="numSelect">

      <label for="arr">Array:</label>
      <input type="text" id="arr">

    </div>
    <div class="square 2">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square 3">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square 4">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square 5">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square 6">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Or you can wrap the `label` and `input` elements in a div, set `display: flex` on the div, and then set `flex-grow: 1` on the input, like this:

```css
.square:nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgb(220, 217, 217);
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33%);
  column-gap: .5%;
}

.square {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.square input {

}
.one div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.one div input {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="square one">

      <div><label for="numSelect">Choose an algorithm:</label>
        <input type="text" id="numSelect"></div>

      <div><label for="arr">Array:</label>
        <input type="text" id="arr"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="square 2">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square 3">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square 4">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square 5">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square 6">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

(You'll have to go full page to see it on one line.)

Comment: This doesn't seem to do what the OP is trying to achieve, here the text is above the input rather than being on the same line as the input.

Comment: @Martin Quoting OP: ```If the input breaks to own line that's fine. I just want it to stretch to the end of the div.```

Comment: I think the OP isn't quite sure what they actually want; this can easily be achieved with `min-width:100%` or similar on the input element.

Comment: Sorry about my ambiguity. I'd wanted the text to be on the same line as input, and only if the window goes below a certain size (will specify later) will the inputs move below to their own line. At any point above that min size, id like the text to be next to the input, and for the input to stretch to the end of the div. (to look like second picture in op) @ajarrow your second solution is exactly what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A work around could be a pseudo, order and flex-grow:

idea demo :

```css
.square:nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgb(220, 217, 217);
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33%);
  column-gap: .5%;
}

.square {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.square.one {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.square.one:before {
  content: '';
  min-width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  order: 1;
  margin:0.5em;
}

.square.one :last-of-type {
  order: 2;
}

.square input {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="square one">

      <label for="numSelect">Choose an algorithm:</label>
      <input type="text" id="numSelect">

      <label for="arr">Array:</label>
      <input type="text" id="arr">

    </div>
    <div class="square 2">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square 3">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square 4">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square 5">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square 6">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

or

```css
.square:nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgb(220, 217, 217);
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20em auto auto;
  column-gap: .5%;
}

.square {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.square.one {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.square.one:before {
  content: '';
  min-width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  order: 1;
  margin:0.5em;
}

.square.one :last-of-type {
  order: 2;
}

.square input {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin:auto  ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="square one">

      <label for="numSelect">Choose an algorithm:</label>
      <input type="text" id="numSelect">

      <label for="arr">Array:</label>
      <input type="text" id="arr">

    </div>
    <div class="square 2">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square 3">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square 4">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square 5">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="square 6">
      <p>buncha text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```